# Why is it necessary to configure an ACL when configuring Dynamic Nat?

Tags: nat

When configuring Dynamic NAT, why is it necessary for us to also create and specify an access list which dictates what kind of traffic should be translated?
[image]

Couldn't we simply skip this step, so that any IP inside our internal network gets translated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Couldn't we simply skip this step, so that any IP inside our internal
> network gets translated?

No, not all addresses on a network need to be translated. Businesses often have public addresses too, and translating those would be unnecessary and counterproductive. There may also be networks inside a business that should not have the possibility of Internet access, and not allowing translation of those addresses is also a security step.

Do not look at this from a home user perspective, but that of a large business network.